# Plotly and cufflinks not working in Anaconda

Tags: python, plotly

I have been doing a course on data science and machine learning and in one of the lesson, it asked me to download and use plotly and cufflinks. I downloaded and installed them successfully, I have imported them successfully as well. But while trying to use them using iplot, it's giving me an error. Below I have attached screenshots of the error so I want to know how to solve this error and use plotly and cufflinks without any issue.

The code that I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
print(__version__)
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4),columns='A B C D'.split())
df.iplot(kind='scatter',x='A',y='B',mode='markers',size=10)
```

The error that I get:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-10-d68919405364> in <module>()
> ----> 1 df.iplot(kind='scatter',x='A',y='B',mode='markers',size=10)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py in _iplot(self, kind, data, layout, filename, sharing, title, xTitle, yTitle, zTitle, theme, colors, colorscale, fill, width, dash, mode, interpolation, symbol, size, barmode, sortbars, bargap, bargroupgap, bins, histnorm, histfunc, orientation, boxpoints, annotations, keys, bestfit, bestfit_colors, mean, mean_colors, categories, x, y, z, text, gridcolor, zerolinecolor, margin, labels, values, secondary_y, secondary_y_title, subplots, shape, error_x, error_y, error_type, locations, lon, lat, asFrame, asDates, asFigure, asImage, dimensions, asPlot, asUrl, online, **kwargs)
>     761                                                                 bargap=bargap,bargroupgap=bargroupgap,annotations=annotations,gridcolor=gridcolor,
>     762                                                            dimensions=dimensions,
> --> 763                               zerolinecolor=zerolinecolor,margin=margin,is3d='3d' in kind,**l_kwargs)
>     764 
>     765         if not data:
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\tools.py in getLayout(kind, theme, title, xTitle, yTitle, zTitle, barmode, bargap, bargroupgap, margin, dimensions, width, height, annotations, is3d, **kwargs)
>     199 
>     200         theme_data = getTheme(theme)
> --> 201         layout=go.Layout(theme_data['layout'])
>     202         layout['xaxis1'].update({'title':xTitle})
>     203         layout['yaxis1'].update({'title':yTitle})
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_layout.py in __init__(self, arg, angularaxis, annotations, autosize, bargap, bargroupgap, barmode, barnorm, boxgap, boxgroupgap, boxmode, calendar, colorway, datarevision, direction, dragmode, font, geo, grid, height, hiddenlabels, hiddenlabelssrc, hidesources, hoverdistance, hoverlabel, hovermode, images, legend, mapbox, margin, orientation, paper_bgcolor, plot_bgcolor, polar, radialaxis, scene, selectdirection, separators, shapes, showlegend, sliders, spikedistance, template, ternary, title, titlefont, updatemenus, violingap, violingroupgap, violinmode, width, xaxis, yaxis, **kwargs)
>    3735         self.images = images if images is not None else _v
>    3736         _v = arg.pop('legend', None)
> -> 3737         self.legend = legend if legend is not None else _v
>    3738         _v = arg.pop('mapbox', None)
>    3739         self.mapbox = mapbox if mapbox is not None else _v
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __setattr__(self, prop, value)
>    3601         if match is None:
>    3602             # Set as ordinary property
> -> 3603             super(BaseLayoutHierarchyType, self).__setattr__(prop, value)
>    3604         else:
>    3605             # Set as subplotid property
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __setattr__(self, prop, value)
>    2702                 prop in self._validators):
>    2703             # Let known properties and private properties through
> -> 2704             super(BasePlotlyType, self).__setattr__(prop, value)
>    2705         else:
>    2706             # Raise error on unknown public properties
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_layout.py in legend(self, val)
>    1224     @legend.setter
>    1225     def legend(self, val):
> -> 1226         self['legend'] = val
>    1227 
>    1228     # mapbox
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __setitem__(self, prop, value)
>    3587         if match is None:
>    3588             # Set as ordinary property
> -> 3589             super(BaseLayoutHierarchyType, self).__setitem__(prop, value)
>    3590         else:
>    3591             # Set as subplotid property
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __setitem__(self, prop, value)
>    2665             # ### Handle compound property ###
>    2666             if isinstance(validator, CompoundValidator):
> -> 2667                 self._set_compound_prop(prop, value)
>    2668 
>    2669             # ### Handle compound array property ###
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _set_compound_prop(self, prop, val)
>    2963         validator = self._validators.get(prop)
>    2964         # type: BasePlotlyType
> -> 2965         val = validator.validate_coerce(val)
>    2966 
>    2967         # Save deep copies of current and new states
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py in validate_coerce(self, v)
>    1790 
>    1791         elif isinstance(v, dict):
> -> 1792             v = self.data_class(**v)
>    1793 
>    1794         elif isinstance(v, self.data_class):
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\layout\_legend.py in __init__(self, arg, bgcolor, bordercolor, borderwidth, font, orientation, tracegroupgap, traceorder, x, xanchor, y, yanchor, **kwargs)
>     500         # ----------------------------------
>     501         _v = arg.pop('bgcolor', None)
> --> 502         self.bgcolor = bgcolor if bgcolor is not None else _v
>     503         _v = arg.pop('bordercolor', None)
>     504         self.bordercolor = bordercolor if bordercolor is not None else _v
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __setattr__(self, prop, value)
>    2702                 prop in self._validators):
>    2703             # Let known properties and private properties through
> -> 2704             super(BasePlotlyType, self).__setattr__(prop, value)
>    2705         else:
>    2706             # Raise error on unknown public properties
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\layout\_legend.py in bgcolor(self, val)
>      62     @bgcolor.setter
>      63     def bgcolor(self, val):
> ---> 64         self['bgcolor'] = val
>      65 
>      66     # bordercolor
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __setitem__(self, prop, value)
>    2674             # ### Handle simple property ###
>    2675             else:
> -> 2676                 self._set_prop(prop, value)
>    2677 
>    2678         # Handle non-scalar case
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _set_prop(self, prop, val)
>    2904         # ------------
>    2905         validator = self._validators.get(prop)
> -> 2906         val = validator.validate_coerce(val)
>    2907 
>    2908         # val is None
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py in validate_coerce(self, v, should_raise)
>    1068             validated_v = self.vc_scalar(v)
>    1069             if validated_v is None and should_raise:
> -> 1070                 self.raise_invalid_val(v)
>    1071 
>    1072             v = validated_v
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py in raise_invalid_val(self, v)
>     214             typ=type_str(v),
>     215             v=repr(v),
> --> 216             valid_clr_desc=self.description()))
>     217 
>     218     def raise_invalid_elements(self, invalid_els):
>
> ValueError: 
>     Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'bgcolor' property of layout.legend
>         Received value: 'pearl02'
>
>     The 'bgcolor' property is a color and may be specified as:
>       - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
>       - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
>       - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
>       - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
>       - A named CSS color:
>             aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,
>             beige, bisque, black, blanchedalmond, blue,
>             blueviolet, brown, burlywood, cadetblue,
>             chartreuse, chocolate, coral, cornflowerblue,
>             cornsilk, crimson, cyan, darkblue, darkcyan,
>             darkgoldenrod, darkgray, darkgrey, darkgreen,
>             darkkhaki, darkmagenta, darkolivegreen, darkorange,
>             darkorchid, darkred, darksalmon, darkseagreen,
>             darkslateblue, darkslategray, darkslategrey,
>             darkturquoise, darkviolet, deeppink, deepskyblue,
>             dimgray, dimgrey, dodgerblue, firebrick,
>             floralwhite, forestgreen, fuchsia, gainsboro,
>             ghostwhite, gold, goldenrod, gray, grey, green,
>             greenyellow, honeydew, hotpink, indianred, indigo,
>             ivory, khaki, lavender, lavenderblush, lawngreen,
>             lemonchiffon, lightblue, lightcoral, lightcyan,
>             lightgoldenrodyellow, lightgray, lightgrey,
>             lightgreen, lightpink, lightsalmon, lightseagreen,
>             lightskyblue, lightslategray, lightslategrey,
>             lightsteelblue, lightyellow, lime, limegreen,
>             linen, magenta, maroon, mediumaquamarine,
>             mediumblue, mediumorchid, mediumpurple,
>             mediumseagreen, mediumslateblue, mediumspringgreen,
>             mediumturquoise, mediumvioletred, midnightblue,
>             mintcream, mistyrose, moccasin, navajowhite, navy,
>             oldlace, olive, olivedrab, orange, orangered,
>             orchid, palegoldenrod, palegreen, paleturquoise,
>             palevioletred, papayawhip, peachpuff, peru, pink,
>             plum, powderblue, purple, red, rosybrown,
>             royalblue, saddlebrown, salmon, sandybrown,
>             seagreen, seashell, sienna, silver, skyblue,
>             slateblue, slategray, slategrey, snow, springgreen,
>             steelblue, tan, teal, thistle, tomato, turquoise,
>             violet, wheat, white, whitesmoke, yellow,
>             yellowgreen
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would get when executed following code?

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import cufflinks as cf
print(__version__)
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4),columns='A B C D'.split())
trace = go.Scatter(x = df['A'], y = df['B'], mode = 'markers')
data = [trace]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

With `plotly.offline.plot` everything work fine but you need only `plotly.plotly.iplot` as I think.
After googling I found the [possible solution](https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/issues/119#issuecomment-403965391) to that - just downgrade your plotly version:

```
pip uninstall plotly
pip install plotly==2.7.0
```

I checked the latest version `plotly` - it is 3.1.1 and this bug also is here. So I am suppose that using version plotly<3.0.0 can solve your problem

Comment: @Madhurjya, hi! My solution helped you?

Comment: No, it didn't work. I tried installing plotly ver 2.7 but it still didn't work

Comment: Error is the same or changed? And you tried downgrade `plotly` to version `2.0.0`, maybe it can help. Do not forget: if you using `python3` then change `pip` to `pip3`

Comment: @Madhurjya, just try switch to `offline` mode. This error show you, that plotly tried to connect with plotly servers. I am updated the answer (just replace `plotly.plotly.iplot` to `plotly.offline.plot`) - and this line of code you set plotly to work in offline mode.

Comment: finally it works. thank you so much.. btw i have another error using scikit. can you pm please if you have the time? I don't know how to message you

Comment: or just `iplot`. Because you set `from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot` and set `init_notebook_mode(connected=True)`, you can just call iplot instead of full `plotly.offline.iplot`. Check additional information [here](https://plot.ly/python/offline/)

Comment: @Madhurjya, it will be better, if you asked on this site (open another question and dont forget specify tag `scikit-learn`). To my regret, I do not have enough experience with `scikit-learn` so I can not help you

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution as of 2019:

This is an error that happens if you have cufflinks version 0.13 or older which was not compatible with plotly 3.0. This may happen because you installed from conda or another source and not with pip.

To solve it, run:

```
pip install cufflinks --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum up as told by @Idodo you have to write the following lines of code in your "Anaconda Prompt" please open this by selecting as an administrator.

for the plotly library

```
conda install -c plotly plotly
```

for the cufflinks library

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-cufflinks
```

then upgrade the cufflinks

```
pip install cufflinks --upgrade
```